# Is it possible to assign hosts for Spark tasks with regex

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop-yarn

Spark on yarn mode, the cluster has nodes like nodeA-xx and nodeB-xx, is there any configurations to launch tasks run on hosts named nodeA-*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using Capacity Scheduler you need to enable the feature called Node labels. [YARN Node Labels](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.8.0/hadoop-yarn/hadoop-yarn-site/NodeLabel.html) won't allow you to specify a regex.  Instead you would have to label the nodes then specify this label as a resource for a queue and then finally run the job against a specific queue.

Comment: YARN Node Labels seems can fixed my case, thank you so much. :)